# VBA - Is there a library for VBA interaction with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, vba, ms-access

Hello happy friendly people! 
My question is a bit general, whether something like this exist. 
I am writing an Excel application, which interacts with SQL Server. This is what I have written until now, just to mimic the command INSERT - `str_generate_order` I have to write similar stuff for each command.

---

**My question is** - is there a library, which is already proven and tested that makes this easier? I really do not want to reinvent the hot water and to test it. I am speaking about the function `str_generate_order` from my code. The code works quite well, just you should specify your own `str_connection_string`, which connects you to a DB. Prety much, I need something like one Python library (which name I do not remember), where you simply give the names of the columns and the command and it does the rest for you... Or should I build it on my own?

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub GenerateDataIntoTable()

    Dim str_table_name      As String: str_table_name = "Main"
    Dim arr_column_names    As Variant
    Dim arr_values          As Variant

    ReDim arr_column_names(6)
    ReDim arr_values(6)

    arr_column_names(0) = "UserName"
    arr_column_names(1) = "CurrentDate"
    arr_column_names(2) = "CurrentTime"
    arr_column_names(3) = "CurrentLocation"
    arr_column_names(4) = "Status1"
    arr_column_names(5) = "Status2"
    arr_column_names(6) = "Status3"

    arr_values(0) = Environ("username")
    arr_values(1) = Date
    arr_values(2) = Time
    arr_values(3) = Application.ActiveWorkbook.FullName
    arr_values(4) = make_random(2, 6)
    arr_values(5) = arr_values(4) + make_random(2, 6)
    arr_values(6) = arr_values(5) - make_random(2, 6)

    Debug.Print b_insert_into_table(str_table_name, arr_column_names, arr_values)

End Sub

Function b_insert_into_table(str_table_name As String, arr_column_names As Variant, arr_values As Variant) As Boolean

    Dim conn            As Object
    Dim str_order       As String

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conn.Open str_connection_string

    str_order = "insert into dbo." & str_table_name
    str_order = str_order & str_generate_order(arr_column_names, arr_values)
    conn.Execute str_order
    conn.Close
    Set conn = Nothing

    b_insert_into_table = True

End Function

Public Function str_generate_order(arr_column_names As Variant, arr_values As Variant) As String

    Dim l_counter       As Long
    Dim str_result      As String

    Dim str_left        As String: str_left = "('"
    Dim str_midd        As String: str_midd = "','"
    Dim str_right       As String: str_right = "')"

    str_result = "("
    For l_counter = LBound(arr_column_names) To UBound(arr_column_names)
        str_result = str_result & arr_column_names(l_counter) & ","
    Next l_counter

    str_result = Left(str_result, Len(str_result) - 1)
    str_result = str_result & ")"
    str_result = str_result & "values"

    str_result = str_result & str_left
    For l_counter = LBound(arr_values) To UBound(arr_values)
        str_result = str_result & arr_values(l_counter)

        If l_counter < UBound(arr_values) Then
            str_result = str_result & str_midd
        Else
            str_result = str_result & str_right
        End If

    Next l_counter

    str_generate_order = str_result

End Function
```

Comment: This is pretty scary to me. The b_insert_into_table method is wide open to sql injection. Why not use a stored procedure with parameters. Do you really change the table definition so frequently that you can't use an explicit list of columns?

Comment: @SeanLange, it is opened to SQL injection, indeed. I would pay attention to this later, this is really internal application, made for small amount of trusted users. So far I don't know how many times I would need to change columns, but the idea is to be as flexible as possible. And exactly because of reasons like this, I am looking for some library or something else.

Comment: Don't get stuck in the trap of "there aren't many users and they all work here" to allow sql injection. It is incredibly difficult to fix injection later, it is easy to fix now. Parameterizing queries is more than just injection proof, it is far easier to maintain and debug.

Comment: I'm the lead developer for a flexible VBA/SQL library that would be perfect for this (https://github.com/Beakerboy/VBA-SQL-Library)

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk - thanks for sharing even on a closed question. In general, I am always happy to see anything developed in VBA. Even, when I go to some companies for other reasons, I am always happy to see their VBA code. Anyway, now the not so fancy stuff - the library is the dream of a 12 year old hacker, who has just heard about SQL injection. (Unfortunately Sean Lange really has a point in both his comments). Looked this part, `ReturnString = "INSERT INTO " & sTable & ImplodeFields` the `sTable` is where the injection can come easily. Still, keep up your interest, thumbs up! :)

Comment: This is a good article on my blog exactly for this - https://www.vitoshacademy.com/automagic-secure-adodb/ (I would have written a disclaimer here, but noone reads the comments of a closed question...)

Comment: @Vityata - Thanks for reviewing the repository. In the README I comment that this should be used with defined data objects. I have a library to interact with Drupal Entities which does this. These DrupalEntity objects define each table schema and use the SQL Library only to build the SQL. It also checks the type of the user-provided data, escapes single quotes, and takes substrings of user-provided strings to ensure that data is not longer than the database field will accept. I agree,the SQL-library I linked to should be one piece of a larger project.

Comment: @KevinNowaczyk - welcome. I just took a quick look. Anyway, make sure to put this info in the README, that it is not injectable with big letters, because of that reason... Some people like me, who read diagonally (and mainly the code) would appreciate it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See [*Materializing any ADODB Query*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46506/23788), [*Creating ADODB Parameters on the fly*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/46312/23788), and if you want to push it then see [*YARPI: Yet Another Repository Pattern Implementation*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/57889/23788) and [*UnitOfWork, an excuse for multiple repositories*](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/60820/23788), all on Code Review Stack Exchange - I've used that `SqlCommand` class for three years since I wrote it, and it has yet to fail me.

[**I put it on GitHub, too**](https://github.com/retailcoder/VBTools/blob/master/SqlCommand.cls)

Oh, and it was written in [vb6](/questions/tagged/vb6) for interacting with [sql-server](/questions/tagged/sql-server), but it works in [vba](/questions/tagged/vba) for interacting with [mysql](/questions/tagged/mysql) just as well - just give it a provider/connection string and if ADODB can handle it, it should "just work".

#### Usage

Selecting a single value with a one-shot connection:

```
Dim result As Variant
SqlCommand.ConnectionString = "connection string"
result = SqlCommand.SelectSingleValue("SELECT SomeField FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeValue = ?", 123)
```

Selecting a result set with a live connection (to support transactions):

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim result As ADODB.Recordset
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
conn.ConnectionString = "connection string"
conn.Open
Set result = cmd.Execute(conn, "SELECT * FROM SomeTable WHERE SomeField = ?", 123)
'use result
result.Close
conn.Close
```

Executing parameterized SQL and passing a connection (to support transactions):

```
Dim cmd As New SqlCommand
Dim conn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim result As Boolean
conn.ConnectionString = "connection string"
conn.Open
result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery(conn, "UPDATE SomeTable SET SomeField = ? WHERE SomeValue = ?", 123, "abc")
conn.Close
```

The `SqlCommand` class determines what ADODB parameters to generate, generates them, along with an actual parameterized ADODB command.

Comment: wow I'm putting this in my default add-in. Very nice work!

Comment: @Brad thanks! There are a number of dependencies though; I'm using a `List` class which uses a `StringFormat` function which uses some regex. Have fun! (and feel free to create issues on the GitHub repo if you notice anything weird)

Comment: Really seems quite what I was expecting. The Python library (which name I do not remember), was using something similar with the "?". Will check it tomorrow. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ADO that's the way to go.

However, you can use it more wisely. You can still make dynamic inserts but you should parameterize them. The SQL Injection stuff is not just about malicious users doing bad things with your data base (unlikely if you are making an Excel Add-in) but more to protect against bad data. They way it is written right now, if you have nay entry in `arr_values` with a `"` your query will be broken. If you have any column in `arr_column_names` with a space, the query will break.

Comment: Thanks. I will probably use the ADO.

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question directly, no there is no specific library you can reference to perform SQL queries. You would have to roll your own effectively using ADO commands and as noted it could be subject to SQLi problems.  You would need to ensure that you validate and handle the inputs carefully.

Comment: Thanks, I will definitely handle the inputs. Pretty much 95% all of them are going to be numbers, thus it should not be an issue.